# Error in flutter: Document references must have an even number of segments

Tags: dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, fatal-error

I have a collection named `memssages` and have to find document where field `begin` is equal to false. Code is like below.

```
Future<String> getRoomID() async {
  QuerySnapshot snapshot = await sl.get<FirebaseAPI>().getFirestore()
    .collection('messages')
    .where('begin',isEqualTo: false).getDocuments();
  if(snapshot.documents.length==0){
    return '';
  } else {
    Random random = Random();
    DocumentSnapshot document = snapshot.documents[random.nextInt(snapshot.documents.length)];
    return document.documentID;
  }
}
```

But It occurs fatal error like my post title.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid document reference.
>   Document references must have an even number of segments, but messages
>   has 1

What is wrong with me? I was suffered whole day...

[Database ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEWkc.png)

Comment: Please add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: @AlexMamo I added

Comment: I doesn't help. Please provide a more detailed one.

Comment: You don't need to know more detail, my problem is related only `messages` collection

Comment: You code works fine, only change i did was - instead of `sl.get<FirebaseAPI>().getFirestore()` i used - `Firestore.instance`. rest is good.

Comment: `sl.get<FirebaseAPI>().getFirestore()` return same `Firestore.instance` because it is singleton instance. Even in this situation, Does it be problem?

Answer (score 3):

Collection Reference will have odd number of segment,
Document Reference will have even number of segment.

Firestore data structure are:
Collection - document - Collection - document - Collection - document

For your case, you are trying to call `getDocument()` from `collectionReference(odd segment)`, however, your code after called `getDocument()`, belongs to `getDocument` from `documentReference(even segment)`. Hence, the error told you your reference need even number of segment.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, then how can I fix it? How can I use `where` clause to get a specific document from collection?

Comment: Solved, it is related to StreamBuilder

Answer (score 1):

Just in case, this can help:

> Go to instance before get

```
final ref = db.collection("users").document(uid).get(); 
print (ref.path); 
final snapShot = await ref;
```